# How do I establish a one-to-many association between two models in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have made two sequelize models, one for storing students and one for storing their tasks.
I want to establish a one to many relation between student and task model...

The task model

```
const Student= require('./student.js')
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Task = sequelize.define("task", {
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });

  Task.associate = (Student) => {
     Task.belongsTo(Student) 
  };
  return Task;
};
```

The Student model

```
const Task = require('./task.js')

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const Student = sequelize.define("student", {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique:true,
        allowNull:false
      },
      branch: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false
      },
      id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
    });

    Student.associate = (Task) =>{
        Student.hasMany(Tasks, {as: "tasks"))
    }
    return Student;
  };
```

I want to fetch the tasks of each student along with the student data..
below is the function for same

// Retrieve all Students from the database.

```
const Task= require('../models/task.js')

exports.findAll = (req, res) => {

    Student.findAll({
      include: Task
    })
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving students."
      });
    });
};
```

But when I hit the query, I get the following error.

```
{
    "message": "task is not associated to student!"
}
```

I'm stuck at this issue for 2 days...kindly help me sort this out.
Thank you in advance

Comment: in the file index.js inside the models file try put this Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
 if (db[modelName].associate) {
  db[modelName].associate(db);
 }
});

Comment: And put the alias inside the include like that: include: {model: Task, as : "task"}